# Cannot import subpackage using __init__.py

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a package structure as follows:

```
package
  __init__.py
  subpackageA
      api.py
      __init__.py
  subpackageB
      action.py
      start.py
      __init__.py
```

The main package only serves to expose one class in subpackageB start.py called Schedule.  All other classes are used internally and cant be exposed.

Therefore my package/__init__.py is as follows:

```
from package.subpackageB.start import Schedule
```

However, when I try to import package, i get the following error:

```
ImportError: No module named 'package.subpackageB'
```

What am I doing wrong here?

**Update**

So after a bit of toiling I realised that my approach was probably wrong for what I was trying to achieve.

I changed it so that api.py, action.py and start.py are no longer in sub packages, but within the main package only.  I then reworked action.py so that its contents where part of start.py.

What this enabled me to do was to use the __all__ parameter to only import the Schedule module I wanted from start.py

As I use api.py it will also be imported by start.py, but this isn't a big issue for now so the new approach works for me.

```
package
  __init__.py
  api.py
  start.py (action.py contents now part of start.py)
```

Comment: What is the command you are using to run your project? At root level try `python -m subpackageB.start`

Comment: All im doing is after I install the package, I start up a python3 command prompt and do import package, then it gives the error I stated in the question.

Comment: @Evusas I get /usr/bin/python3: Error while finding spec for 'package.subpackageB'

Comment: I don't think you executed that `exactly` as I wrote? Just confirm that for me, cheers

Comment: /usr/bin/python3: Error while finding spec for 'subpackageB.start'' (ImportError: No module named 'subpackageB')

Comment: Oh my bad! Now change  `from package.subpackageB.start import Schedule` to `from subpackageB.start import Schedule`. And p.s. Python does not really have `private`, so as long as you keep namespaces separate, this structure should not cause you problems. You can elaborate why you only want to "other classes are used internally and cannot be exposed".

Comment: @Evusas Yeh after much toiling last night I realised how I was organising my package was inherently wrong for what I was trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that this module is kept in path where python does not look for when resolving for package. One thing you can do is add path where this folder is kept to PYTHONPATH environment variable so that python can detect it and import won't fail.

Execute below command on Linux platform:

```
export PYTHONPATH = $PYTHONPATH:/path/to/module
```

Comment: shouldn't `PYTHONPATH` show path to `Python` binary instead to the code?

Comment: Yes. This package is your library which python is not able to detect because it's not in path where it generally check for libraries when you type import any_module.

Comment: if you run your project properly instead of hacking-it-all-up, it will find it. Obviously if he wants to have scripts instead of package, then it's another story.